# How to get the sender address using Pact?

Tags: pact-lang

When using solidity I can get the sender address by using `msg.sender` and when using ink smart contracts I can use `Self::env().caller();`

Can anyone advise what the equivelent would be for Pact? I've had a look at some of the documentation but I think I must be missing it.

Appreciate any guidence you can give.

Thanks,
KB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(chain-data)` is a function that returns some metadata of your transaction. It's documented in the Pact language reference:
https://pact-language.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pact-functions.html#chain-data

You can get the sender value from the function like this:

```
(at 'sender (chain-data))
```

Comment: Thanks - must have skimmed over that.